# Abrindo uma URL a partir do Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

É possível *linkar* um site usando código Python?
Por exemplo, em um menu feito em Tkinter (orientação a objetos) eu queria clicar em botão e ser redirecionado para um site.

Answer (score 4):

O Python possui o pacote [`webbrowser`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/webbrowser.html) nativamente. Neste módulo há definida a função [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.open) que pode ser utilizada para abrir uma URL através do navegador padrão do usuário.

Como você não nos apresentou código algum, deixo um exemplo simples de como seria para abrir a URL ao pressionar um botão:

```
button = Button(frame, text="Abrir URL", command=lambda: webbrowser.open('SUA URL AQUI'))
```